# Problem with changing a combobox in an excel userform by changing another combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have different comboboxes that are located in different frames in an userform. I would like to change the value of combobox1 when i change combobox2 and vice versa when user have checked a checkedbox. It is fairy easy to do so and it works perfectly. BUT the problem is that there is "calculate" button in the userform that calculates the process I want. Although i the combobox2 seems to be changed and identical to combobox1, I get different results for those! I noticed that if i click anywhere in the frame that combobox2 is located, then it is working perfectly. I tried to call force the event update for both comboboxes by calling them but that has not been worked. I wrote the changing the values in Afterupdate, change, click, and exit events, but seems not working! Does anyone have any ideas what i can do for it?  My code simply looks something similar to:

```
If checkbox1.Value = True Then

    Combobox2.Value = Combobox1.Value

End If
```

Comment: I did not understand why you are doing this  Combobox2.Value = Combobox2.Value, I mean why the use of Combox2 on both sides?

Comment: There are alot of different parameters in the userform. Only if the user check the checkbox1 then this two comboboxes should have the same value, otherwise they should have different values!

Comment: but then you should say Combobox1.Value = Combobox2.Value

Comment: How about also fully qualifying your Comboboxes, such as USERFORM1.Combobox1.Value = USERFORM2.Combobox2.value

Comment: @Alok Ah i just saw the typo in my question! the program is working fine and the combobox is changing but it does not be applied when i click on the command button. only i coniseders the new value when i click on frame where the combobox located.

Comment: @Xabier thank you for the suggestion but both of them are located in one USERFORM and even i tried that one to see if there is any difference, but i has not helped

Comment: Can you share complete code of that userform, This is to understand the overall issue better.